# Use go library that does not have go.mod

Tags: go, github

I am new to go and have trouble using a library that does not have a `go.mod` file. The library is https://github.com/yourbasic/graph and I tried installing it according to the instructions given [in the go docs](https://pkg.go.dev/about#adding-a-package). Since I cannot make a request for the version on the repo, I used the `@latest` flag, so in order to install, I executed

```
go install github.com/yourbasic/graph@latest
```

This however fails and says

```
package github.com/yourbasic/graph is not a main package
```

Is there a proper way to install libraries like that? I assume my way of proceeding to just copy the files into a directory within my project is not very clean.

Comment: It's not a main package, you can't install it. That has nothing to do with it missing a `go.mod`. Go will still use the package if you import it, requiring it with a synthesized version string like `v0.0.0-20210606180040-8ecfec1c2869`.

Answer (score 0):

As @JimB said: instead of attempting to install it,

1. Import the package in your code where applicable.
2. Run `go get github.com/yourbasic/graph@latest` — which will download the module (to the local cache) and update your module's `go.mod` file.
3. Build.

The steps 1 and 2 can be swapped, but then the generated `go.mod` entry will have the `// indirect` comment which will disappear next time you run `go mod tidy`.